# Cant Set Struct Property to Enum Rust

Tags: rust

I have a structure textApp with field mode, which has a type of a Mode:

```rust
pub struct textApp{
    mode: Mode,
}

pub enum Mode {
    Single,
    Multiple,
}
```

I initialize a new instance of the textApp structure as myTextApp, and I have a button then when clicked I want it to change the value of myTextApp's .mode field to Mode::Single:

```rust
fn main(){
    let mut myTextApp = textApp{
        mode: Mode::Multiple,
    };

  singleModeBut.set_callback(move||{
     let newMode: Mode = Mode::Single; 
     textApp.mode = newMode;
  //throws an error
  });
}
```

but this gives me the error:

```rust
error[E0423]: expected value, found struct `textApp`
    |                 textApp.mode = newModeSet;
    |                 ^^^^^^^-----
    |                 |
    |                 help: use the path separator to refer to an item: `textApp::mode`
```

Why can't I set this struct field to Mode::Single?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your struct's instance name is `myTextApp`. You are trying to set using struct's name which doesn't make sense.

Changing,

```rust
textApp.mode = newMode;
```

to

```rust
myTextApp.mode = newMode;
```

will fix it.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a11c9aa897460a4e3294b55f263de1f1)

Also, it's a good idea to follow rust style guidelines that ask you to use snake case for identifier names and upper camel case for type names. That will help you avoid such errors.